# Docker server file structure

Tags: docker

Don't know if it is appropriate to ask this question here.
I am new to docker and am trying to find the file/code where the physical memory is malloc for the new container.

I want to manage the pages of the container using userfaultfd. So I want to know where in the docker code is the malloc called to assign the memory pages for the container.

Can someone point me in a direction please.

Comment: In...the Linux kernel source?  Can you help explain what you're looking for a little more?  Is there a specific issue you're trying to resolve?

Comment: Code is here: https://github.com/docker/docker-ce
But docker doesn't really call malloc for the container.  A container is in essence a process (or multiple) which is fenced and the process may call malloc. With that the question makes not really sense.